# Stripe Connect and multi-domain setup

Tags: stripe-payments, multi-tenant, stripe-connect

We are currently looking into implementing Stripe Connect to process payments on a multi-tenant platform. On this platform, each tenant has an own instance of our web application with their own database and their own domain. The deployment is triggered by the client’s online registration and fully automated, so we don’t know in advance when there will be a new application instance.

While this setup doesn’t seem to be a problem in general, we are facing problems with Stripe’s requirement to hardcode several URLs into Stripe’s dashboard, especially the webhook URLs and the return URL for the onboarding workflow. This does obviously not work for us, as we would add the URLs for each domain of our clients.

Is there a way to set these URLs through an API for each tenant or (in regard to webhooks) for a single transaction? Or is there some other way that might work in our scenario?

Answer (score 1):

There is no way set these dynamically but there are workarounds if your instance separation allows it.

For the OAuth flow and the redirect URL you can have a generic URL in your own domain that handles the connection and then redirect to their domain afterwards based on a parameter or the session.

For the webhooks since you're using Connect you can actually receive all the events of the connected accounts in your platform directly:
https://stripe.com/docs/connect/webhooks

The drawback is that you'd need a way to notify their instances that something happened if you need the data stored in their separate databases (or you could handle it locally since you own the full server)